# Divide menu tree parents and children links into columns

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

I have the following menu tree for my main navigation:

- **Parent 1** (= level 0)

  - **SubParent 1** (= level 1)

    - SubChild 1.1 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 1.2 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 1.3 (= level 1)

      - **SubSubParent 1** (= level 2)

        - SubSubChild 1.1 (= level 2)
        - SubSubChild 1.2 (= level 2)
        - SubSubChild 1.3 (= level 2)
  - **SubParent 2** (= level 1)

    - SubChild 2.1 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 2.2 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 2.3 (= level 1)
  - **SubParent 3** (= level 1)

    - SubChild 3.1 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 3.2 (= level 1)
    - SubChild 3.3 (= level 1)
- **Parent 2** (= level 0)

  - etc.

I am building a custom [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com) theme.

I need to build a custom Mega menu dropdown (just theming and styling is my approach), that goes and fit well together with Bootstrap Navbar, dropdown-toggle and so on.

So if you hover or click on e.g. **Parent 1** link you see the following Mega menu dropdown. I want to achieve the following example (see screenshot):

[image: multi column dropdown]

In `menu--main.html.twig` I made the following macro:

```
{# Custom macro for dropdown menu in Megamenu  #}
{% macro submenu_megamenu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    <ul class="list-group-flush">
      {% for item in items %}
        <li>
          {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class':['list-group-item']}) }}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Then my menu_link macro:

```
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass(['navbar-nav', 'mr-auto']) }}>
        {% for item in items %}
          {%
            set classes_list_item = [
            'nav-item',
            item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown',
            'navigation'
          ]
          %}
          {%
            set classes_link = [
            'nav-item',
            'nav-link',
            item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown-toggle',
            item.is_collapsed ? 'dropdown-toggle',
            item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
          ]
          %}
          <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes_list_item) }}>
            {% if item.below %}
              {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class': classes_link, 'data-toggle' : 'dropdown' }) }}
              {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
            {% else %}
              {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class': classes_link }) }}
            {% endif %}
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      {% elseif menu_level == 1 %}
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu__large">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              {% for item in items %}
                {%
                  set classes_link = [
                  'dropdown-item',
                  item.is_expanded ? 'dropdown-toggle',
                  item.is_collapsed ? 'dropdown-toggle',
                  item.in_active_trail ? 'active',
                ]
                %}
                <div class="col col-lg-3">
                  {{ link(item.title, item.url, { 'class': classes_link }) }}
                  {% if item.below %}
                    {{ menus.submenu_megamenu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
                  {% endif %}
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          {% else %}
           ???
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Ok I am getting close. It's adding now different CSS classes and HTML markup to level 0 and level 1 links. The `level 1` parents (and it's Childs) are divided into (4) columns. And it's expanding the childs.

But how do I render **SubSubParent 1** (= level 2) and it's childs into the same column as it's parent (like on the example screenshot in the first column)?

Comment: Did you try WE Megamenu (https://www.drupal.org/project/we_megamenu)?

Comment: @Paul thank you. Because I have to divide them into columns only and want a smooth integration into my custom Bootstrap 4 theme, actually I don't want to use any module, and the overload of an extra module...

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: @KTM yes. I will answer my question when I have time.